# Windows 10 update on dual boot, can't boot into ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, updates

I decided to update my windows 7 install to windows 10, after which my grub was lost. So I used an ubuntu live usb with boot-repair and it found my win10 install. But I no longer have the option to boot into ubuntu. The partitiontable says its in extended space. How do I recover ubuntu? (system= x220 dualboot windows 10 + ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal in Windows 10 (Administrator Mode)

Type `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} "path\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi"`

Reboot. See if this helps?

Comment: I get: the element data type specified is not recognized, or does not apply to the specified entry.